accelerate re-syncing for a large file (> 3 TB) with rsync
How to accelerate re-syncing large file (>3 TB) which got few of its blocks changed (< 1 GB) with rsync.
AFAIK, rsync will do checksum comparison between src/dst blocks to find the differences and then sync them.
Is there a way to increase concurrency at the checksum comparison stage to accelerate the sync?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/743721 ?

@ArtemS.Tashkinov --partial helps with interrupted transfers, and --inplace helps with not first copying over (dst-locally) the unmodified parts, and changes, and then do a replacement, but that has implications on robustness and bears no benefit on file systems that can do no-duplication copies through a reflink mechanism (XFS, btrfs, ZFS). So, --partial doesn't help here, --inplace might save a bit of IO on the destination side, but neither accelerate re-syncing, I'm afraid!

Is this a local to local copy? Or between two systems over a network?

Not really, no!
rsync, as you probably noticed, does indeed do block-wise hashing, all by itself.
It can use a variety of hashes, but on any somewhat modern combination of server and client rsync versions, that is going to be xxh128, xxh3 or the classical xxhash (xxh64). Benchmarks suggest that these run at ca 30 GB/s on a somewhat modern CPU. That's faster than 8× PCIe 5.0 lanes (and I'm not aware of any non-data-center-array-add-things-up-cumulatively storage that would reach that speed).
In other words, the block checksumming doesn't make sense to make more concurrent – fetching of data works fastest if you just read sequentially from your storage (or storage array), because that's exactly what prefetching would optimize, anyways. Your CPU is sufficiently much faster than your storage that there.
You mention the checksum comparison as the bottleneck, that's happening in the source code here, with the bulk of the computation probably happening in the hash_search function.
There's nothing configurable there, as far as I can tell, aside from updating_basis_file (which is the --inplace option mentioned in the comments), and the block size; I think it marginally slows down comparisons, but I'm not sure. The search is relatively simple:

you checksum each block (say, using xxh128),
you calculate the MD4-hash of the checksum to keep the hashtable size at bay
you check whether you've seen the same hash before
if you have, you actually go back and check the (much lower-collision-probability) original checksums (instead of just their hashes). If they match, that's a block you don't need to transfer!

So, not really much you could, on short notice, do to increase speed there; you should mostly be RAM throughput limited there!
But by all means, experiment and increase the block size (--block-size, it's in bytes) to something larger than the 217 B (128 kB) default block size for huge files. You might be transferring more than you need – but it would speed up the search.

"rsync, as you probably noticed, does indeed do block-wise hashing, all by itself" - but usefully, only over a network connection that it can manage. Otherwise it defaults to a full file transfer

@Marcus: Thanks for your feedback. But I think that with high IOPS flash storage, parallel threads should go faster than sequentially. Anyway, this is not an option as you have mentioned.
For --block-size,128 kB is the max block size, not the default one (https://github.com/RsyncProject/rsync/blob/9615a2492bbf96bc145e738ebff55bbb91e0bbee/rsync.h#L160)

@LeoMan not really, no, you are still limited by IO/s, and whether you read that sequentially or not doesn't matter – you can't get faster than that, and your OS will pre-fetch blocks linearly

The following idea looking at the problem.
Currently it is at every sync:

scan full checksum of source
scan full checksum of target
transfer diff

So dependent on the IO discussion if IO of 1) is faster than IO of 2)
It may be a consideration to try to avoid the scanning (of 2)), by keeping the checksum metadata for the next run.
What you need in this case is a checksummer (maybe self written) which does in one IO stream chunked checksumming and full, like in peaces like:

3TB hash
a. 1.5Tb hash
b. 1.5TB hash
a. 750GB hash
b. 750GB hash
c. 750GB hash
d. 750GB hash

...
down to the acceptable change window of e.g. 8k.

a. 8k hash
b. 8k hash..
aaaaa. 8k hash

that you use comparing in a tree structure to the last run (target) and therefore know what branches in the tree you need to follow down to the smallest change window leaf.
This list you would copy, and take the hash metadata as source for the next sync.
Even better would be if you know the writes to the source, so re-scanning would be limited to those branch elements, if needed at all.
Alternative
This you would get for free if you change the storage system to something like zfs, doing snapshots and do then block based incremental sends and receives of the snapshots, which truly represent just changed ranges in the source.
Sorry that the best which comes to my mind.
Update:
As i just learn python, i gave it a try and learned, if you merge the scanner and the hash compare no need for the tree structure.
time python3 ./filehasher.py  /export/disk-1/zfs.cache.raw 
Namespace(inputfile='/export/disk-1/zfs.cache.raw', min_chunk_size=8192)
os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=12, st_dev=2065, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=2147479552, st_atime=1728674135, st_mtime=1728674159, st_ctime=1728674159)
File Size in Bytes is 2147479552
File Size in Bytes is 31 exp 2147483648 min_chunk_exp 13
- load old hashes...
We need 1048574 hashes for this file.
chunk 512 of 0.20% 
diff 13:512 o 124a33e4488e3b10a5434f24789173fad96014a4cc46856289b2b7f04aa41538 != n ea42ae1df2ce719035f0c51e3369ebe4e6b8b9dd9c44e2b60c3084a0efeedbcc
chunk 145991 of 55.69% 
diff 13:145991 o a9198b4af91db0d5eeb4ad53d1c41302952071c3926713f74558c83d0e901f1e != n 0abfad615307b69f406d089104c0c12c05d197c3e3d9b072894780b9b1c93f88
chunk 145992 of 55.69% 
diff 13:145992 o c89ae8a8c82edc9d2045eaad344887ae00878f6066fa3893cd42e7f9fa02c5b4 != n 4a9586bca78224d2c7343abcccd0e2138e2a416d806be72788cef3cdd84e1a2f
chunk 145993 of 55.69% 
diff 13:145993 o f882619b014bc284101769ab9d2dc3b017f3fa9873a352a566f03fcb805aee1b != n 97f1aeb56c68be8b524aa480636d6987a75c88cc93f941b8cbe76043d108eabe
chunk 145994 of 55.69% 
...cut...
diff 13:146274 o 10b911c4ccc35dfc91f5025eee0b17fd96e9ea7a8c38896e2bda824ec3a6d618 != n 1946f829b181b95cd95c9071f70a300700f8d3e25ac6e00758f7779e99e1bdde
chunk 146275 of 55.80% 
diff 13:146275 o c201a9773aba93789a7c0191901b5a0cb04a4eafb90ef6bd225bb89ebc0d0294 != n f7bc8527c8585f680a32940c72ff0d300a95e2d6ddf0341d5892133c225592b8
chunk 146276 of 55.80% 
diff 13:146276 o c311d18dfe474cb60aaaf63ecb20b70a7a8a4959a30e986661b79b2ceab8d50c != n d823513af052881feae29e5706c687051b3f54fa894a3b97b94e67eac2594adc
chunk 262143 of 100.00% 
write hashes...

real    0m25.236s
user    0m14.316s
sys     0m4.296s

Code looks like: (please mind no support :) )
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("filehasher")
parser.add_argument("inputfile", help="file which should be hashed.", type=str)
parser.add_argument("--min-chunk-size", help="smallest chunk for hashing.", type=int, default=8192)
args = parser.parse_args()

print (args)

import os

file_stats = os.stat(args.inputfile)

print(file_stats)
print(f'File Size in Bytes is {file_stats.st_size}')

import math
two_exp=math.log(file_stats.st_size,2)
if two_exp-int(two_exp) > 0:
    two_exp=int(two_exp)+1
else:
    two_exp=int(two_exp)
two_exp_mchung=int(math.log(args.min_chunk_size,2))

print(f'File Size in Bytes is {two_exp} exp {2**two_exp} min_chunk_exp {two_exp_mchung}')

sum_hashes=0
multi=2
hash_obj={}
hash_max_size={}
hash_max_current={}
hash_obj_idx={}

import pickle
#args.inputfile+".pickle"
pickle_filename="./hash.pickle."+str(args.min_chunk_size)
old_hash=False

if os.path.isfile(pickle_filename):
   print("- load old hashes...")
   old_hash=True
   with open(pickle_filename, 'rb') as handle:
      old_hash_obj = pickle.load(handle)

import hashlib

for idx in range(two_exp,two_exp_mchung - 1,-1):
   # print(f"{idx} needs {multi} hashes")
   hash_obj_idx[idx]=0
   hash_obj[idx]={}
   hash_obj[idx][hash_obj_idx[idx]]=hashlib.sha256(b"")
   hash_max_size[idx]=2**idx
   hash_max_current[idx]=2**idx
   sum_hashes=sum_hashes+multi
   multi=multi*2

print(f"We need {sum_hashes} hashes for this file.")

def read_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size=1024):
    """Lazy function (generator) to read a file piece by piece.
    Default chunk size: 1k."""
    while True:
        data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
        if not data:
            break
        #print(f"reading {len(data)}")
        yield bytes(data)

def hashing_tree(data):
    data_len=len(data)
    #print(f"hashing of {data_len}")
    for idx in range(two_exp,two_exp_mchung - 1,-1):
        hash_obj[idx][hash_obj_idx[idx]].update(data)
        hash_max_current[idx]=hash_max_current[idx]-data_len
        #print(f"update hash exp = {idx}...{hash_max_size[idx]} - remaining in idx {hash_max_current[idx]}")
        if hash_max_current[idx] == 0:
            #print(f"idx cycle {idx} from {hash_obj_idx[idx]} to {(hash_obj_idx[idx]+1)}")
            # cycle of idx
            # 1. reset to max
            hash_max_current[idx]=hash_max_size[idx]
            # 2. increase index
            hash_obj_idx[idx]=hash_obj_idx[idx]+1
            hash_obj[idx][hash_obj_idx[idx]]=hashlib.sha256(b"")

def hashing_flat(data):
   data_len=len(data)
   #print(f"hashing of {data_len}")
   idx=two_exp_mchung
   hash_obj[idx][hash_obj_idx[idx]].update(data)
   hash_max_current[idx]=hash_max_current[idx]-data_len
   #print(f"update hash exp = {idx}...{hash_max_size[idx]} - remaining in idx {hash_max_current[idx]}")
   if hash_max_current[idx] == 0:
      #print(f"idx cycle {idx} from {hash_obj_idx[idx]} to {(hash_obj_idx[idx]+1)}")
      # cycle of idx
      # 1. reset to max
      hash_max_current[idx]=hash_max_size[idx]
      # 2. increase index
      # 2.1 convert obj to str for pickling
      hash_obj[idx][hash_obj_idx[idx]]=hash_obj[idx][hash_obj_idx[idx]].hexdigest()
      if old_hash:
         if old_hash_obj[idx][hash_obj_idx[idx]] == hash_obj[idx][hash_obj_idx[idx]]:
            pass
            #print("")
            #print(f"ok {idx}:{hash_obj_idx[idx]}")
         else:
            print("")
            print(f"diff {idx}:{hash_obj_idx[idx]} o {old_hash_obj[idx][hash_obj_idx[idx]]} != n {hash_obj[idx][hash_obj_idx[idx]]}")
      # 2.2 move on...
      hash_obj_idx[idx]=hash_obj_idx[idx]+1
      hash_obj[idx][hash_obj_idx[idx]]=hashlib.sha256(b"")


chk=int(0)
max_chk=int(file_stats.st_size/args.min_chunk_size)
with open(args.inputfile,"rb") as f:
    for piece in read_in_chunks(f,args.min_chunk_size):
        print(f"chunk {chk} of {(chk*100/max_chk):3.2f}% ", end="\r")
        hashing_flat(piece)
        chk=chk+1
        #break
        # process_data(piece)


# convert last item
for idx in range(two_exp,two_exp_mchung - 1,-1):
   hash_obj[idx][hash_obj_idx[idx]]=hash_obj[idx][hash_obj_idx[idx]].hexdigest()

#import json
#print(json.dumps(hash_obj))
#exit(0)

print("")
print("write hashes...")

with open(pickle_filename, 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(hash_obj, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)


#print(a == b)


You are close to describing how rsync works - it builds a tree of hashes of the file structure spanning different regions. The the client and server find the differing branches in order to identify the delta. See first paragraph of description in man page.

Thx for your comment, sure i am aware of it, but the difference i tried to point out is that one can safe the state of the hashes if the target is known to be read-only and if you have a lot of hashes you most likely want to have a tree instead of a list.
Nevertheless i guess the alternatives serves the purpose best (block replicated storage)
